# Design change to switch from Oracle Materialized view to simple view

Tags: view, materialized-views, oracle19c

We are using Oracle Materialized view to extract data for a reporting system.  The setting of the MV is to refresh on every commit.
After migrating to Oracle 19 form Oracle 12 system was very slow for few days and eventually became unresponsive after few days due to various bugs in Oracle 19 related to Materialized View.
We did a workaround of changing MV setting from on commit to OnDemand every 5 min to solve this issue.

The parent table on which this view is created gets updated every second and has 2 million records.
Having a MV on a table which is updated so frequently is fundamentally not a good design.

We don't want to depend on Oracle patches to fix this and planning to redesign this table.
Can I change this view to simple view and possibly apply all possible ways to improve query response time and expect that I will have view query returned in few seconds given I have 2 mil records in Parent table.
Assume that table has basic datatypes only and view is reading about 5-6 fields.

We tried oncommit to ondemand as a workaround but as per the business need, we need committed data for the reporting system and cannot be delayed more than one min.

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Is the question "can I write a view that could be queried to return 2 million rows in a few seconds"?  If so, a great deal depends on what that view is supposed to be doing-- are you, for example, aggregating 1 billion rows to produce the 2 million rows of output?  Or are you doing a simple `select` against the base table that will involve a full table scan of a 2 million row table?

Comment: thanks Justin. I am supposed to do a simple select against the base table that will involve a full table scan of a 2 million rows.

Comment: Oracle can probably return that much data in a few seconds.  You'd need to benchmark your query performance in your environment to be sure.  Whether the process that consumes that data can consume 2 million rows, particularly if you're sending data over the network, is something that you would also need to benchmark.  I'm not seeing a question here that someone who isn't in your environment to test it could possibly answer.